# C# ASP.NET Core Web API - EF Core one-to-many relation - a possible object cycle was detected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am following the Entity Framework Core docs where it shows how to make an one-to-many relation between two objects without it being required. Strictly following this I get a error:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many#optional-one-to-many

```
builder.Services
       .AddControllers()
       .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

This error makes sense when you think about it and I know adding the code above will ignore the error. But I do not just want to ignore this. What would be the best practice of avoiding this but still being able to achieve what I want to achieve? Or is ignoring this really the best thing to do?

Here is some code and explanation:

I am creating a sort of to-do / to-buy list. Now I have multiple items with categories. But I want to have for example a recipe (`ParentItem`) where other items can fall under (as example chicken and rice recipe has the items chicken and rice).

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public CategoryModel Category { get; set; }
    public long? ParentItemId { get; set; }
    public ParentItemModel? ParentItem { get; set; }
}

public class ParentItemModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CategoryModel Category { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemModel> Items { get; } = new List<ItemModel>();
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ParentItemModel>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Items)
        .WithOne(i => i.ParentItem)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentItemId)
        .IsRequired(false);
}
```

This is basically the same as said in the docs (linked above)

Comment: you missed the part `For cases where the navigations, foreign key, or required/optional nature of the relationship are not discovered by convention, these things can be configured explicitly` so in your case you don't need OnModelCreating for that relations ship

Comment: Removing the OnModelCreating leaves me with the same: A possible object cycle was detected. Was worth the try tho

Comment: The simplest answer is "don't serialize entities". Entities and their navigation properties serve the data domain. For data transport you have different needs and limitations. Create DTOs to serve the needs of transport, with uni-directional references to avoid issues like this, then project those from the entities using `Select` or `ProjectTo` (I.e. Automapper)

Comment: @Daegarys `public ICollection<ItemModel> Items { get; } = new List<ItemModel>();`will also be redundant, your code referents ParentItemModel id and ICollection<ItemModel> the id from itemmodel, so when you enter a row, the id must exist prior to the enter of the row which is impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not related to EntityFramework. It's about JSON deserialization. You have class `Foo` which owns a property of type `Bar`, and class `Bar` also have a property of type `Foo`. Imagine the output JSON string of such structure... I wouldn't recommend ignoring all cycles at once, but rather just investigate your code and identify such cycles, after that put a `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on a "from-child-to-parent" dependency. This should save your time.